# How to schedule ETL based on status recorded within a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have some code embedded within SSIS which regularly checks the status of an ETL job recorded in a table to see if it is currently running or not:

```
select CASE WHEN ETL_STATUS = 'Running'
        THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END  As CanETLbeExecuted
from (SELECT 1 As DummyColumn from DUAL) DummyRow 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETL_TABLE ON 1=1 AND JOB = 'Load new files' AND ETL_ID = (SELECT MAX(ETL_ID) FROM ETL_TABLE);
```

My ETL_TABLE looks something like this:

| ETL_ID | JOB | ETL_STATUS | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192032 | Archive files > 30 days | Running | 2023-02-11 11:30:01 |  |
| 192843 | Load new files | Completed | 2023-02-11 10:45:02 | 2023-02-11 11:01:23 |
| 872632 | Business task execute | Completed | 2023-02-11 09:45:01 | 2023-02-11 09:50:00 |
| 387382 | Business task execute | Completed | 2023-02-11 09:01:23 | 2023-02-11 09:15:35 |
| 199143 | Load new files | Completed | 2023-02-11 08:11:45 | 2023-02-11 08:24:25 |

If the ETL is running ("Yes") then it means the next scheduled running of ETL should not be run till its completed, however if it is "No" then the next ETL instance can run.

The code I currently have is only selecting the MAX ETL_ID from the entire table and not just the max for "Load new files" ETL for example. This means that it will take the ETL_ID from the latest ETL which is "Archive files > 30 days" and not the ETL_ID for the most recent "Load new files" row.

Is there a better code so that it gets the lastest ROW_ID for the most recent "Load new files"? For instance, It should look for ETL_ID '192843' not '192032'.

Comment: `where JOB = 'Load new files'` in the subquery?

Comment: @astentx I've tried including that in the subquery however it doesnt seem to work as it still looks at the latest row instead of the latest specific ETL instance

Comment: So your basic query seems to be incorrect, because you want most recent (by start_date?), not the maximum one, right?

Comment: @astentx Yes I guess it would make sense to do it by start_date rather than maximum ETL_ID but not sure how to go about doing that as when I use MAX next to the date it doesnt work. Just a little stuck there

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can modify your where clause to include ETL_STATUS also and see it works

```
-- not tested
select CASE WHEN ETL_STATUS = 'Running'
        THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END  As CanETLbeExecuted
from (SELECT 1 As DummyColumn from DUAL) DummyRow 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETL_TABLE ON 1=1 AND JOB = 'Load new files' AND ETL_ID = (SELECT MAX(ETL_ID) FROM ETL_TABLE WHERE ETL_STATUS  = 'Running');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still does the same thing and prints "Yes" even though the ETL is not running

Comment: Hi , did you try using the filter on column Job and see if that helps  AND job  = 'Load new files'

Comment: Still does not work for me when I do that :( Not sure what is wrong with the code

Comment: Check if there are spaces in the column by using Trim and see if it works

Comment: Yes Ive checked this and still no luck, showing the same values as before

Comment: Can you just run your query by filtering on ETL_ID = 192032 and see if it gets the rows. After that add the filter on the column job =  'Load new files' and see if you get data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252702/discussion-between-himanshu-kandpal-and-r-sem).